# Best way to "group" items "virtually"?

Tags: wpf

I'm working on a custom items based WPF control. For the "normal" layout, think vertical StackPanel, so my xaml would look something like:

```
<mycontrol>
 <item1 />
 <item2 />
 <item3 />
</mycontrol>
```

In this case, its simple, 3 item containers are created and all is good. The control will look like:

```
[item1]
[item2]
[item3]
```

Use case #2 is, I need to support horizontal "grouping"... ideally my xaml would look like:

```
<mycontrol>
 <item1 />
 <stackpanel orientation=horizontal>
  <item2a />
  <item2b />
  <item2c />
 </stackpanel>
 <item3 />
</mycontrol>
```

and in this case, I would render as:

```
[item1]
[item2a] [item2b] [item2c]
[item3]
```

So, what I'm going for is *5* item containers being generated. I've already worked out a custom layout panel and that part works.

The issue is, if I use a stackpanel, I'll only get *3* item containers which makes sense, duh, but it breaks the keyboard interface of the control. I could do something hacky where I intercept all the keyboard and mouse stuff and "re-route" it in this case, but that seems hacky and difficult to get to work in a generic way.

Is there something obscure built into WPF to deal with this? The "sub items" getting generated as thier own containers?

The way I'm currently heading is to do something like:

```
<item1 />
<item2a isGrouped=true />
<item2b isGrouped=true />
<item2c isGrouped=true />
<item3 />
```

So, when I hit the first isGrouped=true, it'll start grouping until it hits a false, but I'm not crazy about that either because I'll have to make isGrouped a 3 state enum so I can have one group right below another group. Also, the hierarchy is not clear in the xaml.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe use Grid and put your "horizontal" items into same different columns? Whereas normal items will go to separate rows?

Comment: The control ItemsControl works based on item containers. If I put 2a,2b,2c in a child control, the container will get put around the child control and not for each 2a, 2b, 2c like I want.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get more or less the look you are going for using a [HierarchicalDataTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate.aspx) within a [TreeView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeview.aspx) that uses a custom `TreeViewItem` control template. For the control template, I simply copied the [example template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752048.aspx) and made a few modifications. All of the containers are in the right place, but the keyboard navigation doesn't work on the nested items (because `TreeView` is not expecting that layout I guess). Here is what I came up with:

```xml
<TreeView
    ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <Color x:Key="SelectedBackgroundColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
        <Color x:Key="SelectedUnfocusedColor">#FFDDDDDD</Color>
        <Style
            TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter
                Property="ItemsPanel">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter
                Property="IsExpanded"
                Value="True" />
            <Setter
                Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <!-- This template came from the example template and has just a few modifications.
                            Example is at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752048.aspx -->
                    <ControlTemplate
                        TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                        <Grid>
                            <!-- Changed the grid configuration -->
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <!-- The entire VisualStateGroups section is a direct copy+paste from the example template -->
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="Bd"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame
                                            KeyTime="0"
                                            Value="{StaticResource SelectedBackgroundColor}" />
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="SelectedInactive">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="Bd"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame
                                            KeyTime="0"
                                            Value="{StaticResource SelectedUnfocusedColor}" />
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ExpansionStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Expanded">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsHost">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
                                            KeyTime="0"
                                            Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Collapsed" />
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <!-- Removed the ToggleButton -->
                            <!-- Tweaked the placement of items in the grid -->
                            <Border
                                x:Name="Bd"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                                <ContentPresenter
                                    x:Name="PART_Header"
                                    ContentSource="Header"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"/>
                            </Border>
                            <ItemsPresenter
                                x:Name="ItemsHost"
                                Grid.Column="1" />
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <!-- Removed the IsExpanded trigger -->
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="HasHeader" Value="false" />
                                    <Condition Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter
                                    TargetName="PART_Header"
                                    Property="MinWidth"
                                    Value="75" />
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="HasHeader" Value="false" />
                                    <Condition Property="Height" Value="Auto" />
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter
                                    TargetName="PART_Header"
                                    Property="MinHeight"
                                    Value="19" />
                            </MultiTrigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.Resources>
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate
            DataType="{x:Type local:MyItem}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

For reference, my `ItemsSource` property is bound to a collection containing items that look like this:

```
internal class MyItem
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public List<MyItem> Children { get; private set; }

    public MyItem(string name = null)
    {
        Name = name;
        Children = new List<MyItem>();
    }
}
```

This is done without creating a custom control, but hopefully it gives you an idea of what you can do. The combination of a `HeirarchicalDataTemplate` and a specialized container type (in my case `TreeViewItem` with a custom control template) is key to the way I did it.

Here is some data that I tested with and the result:

```
public IEnumerable<MyItem> Items { get; private set; }

...

var items = new MyItem[]
{
    new MyItem("[First]"),
    new MyItem(),
    new MyItem("[Third]")
};
items[1].Children.Add(new MyItem("[Second_0]"));
items[1].Children.Add(new MyItem("[Second_1]"));
items[1].Children.Add(new MyItem("[Second_2]"));
Items = items;
```

[image: Screenshot]

I am sure the visualization could be improved. I just threw this together in under 10 minutes.

Comment: Thanks for your work, but I think you misunderstood my question. I already have a working control. I was just trying to see if there was a cool way to specify the "sub items" in an easy to read way *in XAML*.  Maybe with a Markup extension or something like that?